# How to stop android service?

Tags: android

I have created a android service. I start the service and stop the service using startService(intent) and stopService(intent).

My problem is that even i stop the service; it starts again without any explicit call to startService.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Post some code examples, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop

Comment: other questions with very similar topics seem to answer this one: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265217/why-cant-i-stop-a-service-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

without proper code samples, this is difficult, but chances are that you have a bound services that is not unbound yet.

in case you dont have it bound, "this.stopSelf()" from within the service is one of the ways to do the trick:

```
public class BatchUploadGpsData extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "here i am, rockin like a hurricane.   onCreate service");
        this.stopSelf();
    }
```

this is an actual code snippet from testing code that works on android 2.2 and up

Comment: Wouldn't stopSelf() stop the service as soon as it is started?  How can we let the service run then?

Comment: @IgorG.  in this case it stops the service right after it executes its one and only line of code.  imagine that there are thousands of lines of code BEFORE "this.StopSelf()".